# How to get data with same id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called perform which contains pid (performer's id) and vid (video's id) like this:

```
+---------+------+
| pid     | vid  | 
+---------+------+
| 2303485 | 2    | 
| 2305672 | 2    |
|  ...    | ...  |
+---------+------+
```

My question is, given by a video's id, how to get all of the videos performed by actors in the given video.

My solution is:

```
select vid 
  from perform 
 where pid in (select pid from perform where vid = 2)
```

However, this takes 30s or even longer. How can I improve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT vid FROM perform WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM perform WHERE vid = 2)
```

or this:

```
SELECT p1.vid
FROM perform AS p1
INNER JOIN perform AS p2 ON p2.pid = p1.pid AND p2.vid = 2
GROUP BY p1.vid
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p2' in 'on clause'